# Determining Fluorescence Quantum Yield of C60 in Toluene

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, photochemistry, spectrophotometry

For my experiment, I am trying to determine the fluorescence quantum yield of C60-fullerene in toluene (at room temperature).  In order to do that, I need to have a standard sample with a valid and known fluorescence quantum yield. I have been looking for a standard sample with a known quantum yield in toluene, however, I am not sure of what to use.

Would it be better if I used a different solvent in determining the quantum yield and if so what solvent and standard should I use.

Comment: A fairly popular standard is Rhodamine 6G, in some sort of alcohol. Be aware that if you decide to use a different solvent, you'll have to account for differences in refractive index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toluene instead of benzene can be a poor choice when H-atom abstraction by the excited state is possible. Here, you're safe.

Try to get a copy of [Fluorescence spectra and quantum yields of buckminsterfullerene (C60) in room-temperature solutions. No excitation wavelength dependence](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja00067a062).

The authors apparently used 9-cyanoanthracene in toluene as a standard to determine $\Phi_f$ of C60.

You might also want to have a look for review articles by *Dirk Guldi* from the time around 2000; I remember him giving a number of talks on C60 around that time.

Comment: In addition you should use a standard with emission in the same region as you sample to avoid effects of detector etc effects with wavelength. Porphyrins are probably good here as there are standard corrected spectra published.  Automatic correction, as used in some fluorimeters, is not always as good as its made out to be.